# Is it always better to use the RobustScaler (vs StandardScaler)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

From reading the docs, I believe the RobustScaler is more immune to outliers that the StandardScaler. In that case, why not just use the RobustScaler always?